# How to vectorize an R function with arguments that can be supplied with NULL values?

Tags: r

What is the best way to vectorize an R function with arguments that accept vectors, static values, and `NULL`s? I'm running into a problem when I `Map()` a function with arguments that are sometimes supplied with `NULL`s. I get the follow error message (replicated using the code below):

`Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length`

To replicate this problem, I've written a function that returns `n` simulated values using parameters from `data` with optionally implemented `min` and `max` values.

```
#' foo (example function with some args defaulting to NULL)
#'
#' Returns simulated normal values using population parameters from data
#' 
#' @param data Numeric vector used to calculate population parameters
#' @param n Number of simulated data points to return
#' @param min Optional. Creates a truncation effect. Simulated values
#'   below min will be replaced with min.
#' @param max Optional. Creates a truncation effect. Simulated values
#'   above max will be replaced with max.
#' @return Numeric vector of simulated values.
foo <- function(data, n, min = NULL, max = NULL) {
  x <- rnorm(n, mean(data), sd(data))
  if (!is.null(min)) {
    x[x < min] <- min
  }
  if (!is.null(max)) {
    x[x > max] <- max
  }
  x
}
```

I'm working with lists and would like the function to return lists. So, here, the data vector is a list of numeric vectors.

```
## data vector
data <- replicate(5, rnorm(3), simplify = FALSE)
```

Other arguments can accept static (`length(x) == 1`) or dynamic values (`length(x) == length(data)`). When non-NULL values are supplied, it works whether args are given one or multiple values.

```
## static args (this works)
n <- 10
min <- -1.96
max <- 1.96
Map(foo, data, n, min, max)

## vector args (this works)
n <- sample(2:100, 5)
min <- runif(5, -4, -1)
max <- runif(5, 1, 4)
Map(foo, data, n, min, max)
```

But when args are passed a `NULL` value it breaks.

```
## null args (this doesn't work)
n <- sample(2:100, 5)
min <- NULL
max <- NULL
Map(foo, data, n, min, max)

## it doesn't matter if n is a vector
n <- 10
min <- NULL
max <- NULL
Map(foo, data, n, min, max)


Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
```

Comment: Do you want to use the `mean` of *each* vector in your input list? Or the `mean` of  *all* vectors (aggregate) in your input list?

Comment: This is not the actual function I'm trying to fix, but the equivalent would be to assume I want to use each vector independently.

Comment: Since in your function, you declare `min=NULL` and `max=NULL`, you can get away with not passing `min` and `max` in your call. Using `Map(foo,data,10)` works for me.

Comment: This is to be used as a function so sometimes it will be given NULLs sometimes not. I realize I could create a different `Map()` call for each permutation that doesn't include a potentially `NULL` value, but the actual function in question has several args defaulting to NULL, so I'd rather have it done in one shot.

Comment: Pass `Map(foo,data,10,NA,NA)` instead? `min <- NA` and `max <- NA`...

Comment: That'll throw an error. If it helps, these are parameters in http  requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the code you're looking for is

```
n <- sample(2:100, 5)
min <- list(NULL)
max <- list(NULL)
Map(foo, data, n, min, max)
```

The `Map` function expects each argument after the function to be a vector or list of arguments, which will be recycled to the length of the longest one. So in this case, we have `length(data)` and `length(n)` equal to 5 and `length(min)` and `length(max)` equal to 1, so the single NULL in the min and max lists is recycled 5 times and passed to the function each time.

Alternatively, if you want to do an "apply"-like operation where some arguments are vectors and others are scalars (i.e. single values to be passed to every call of the function), use `mapply`, passing the vector args directly and the scalar args inside `MoreArgs`:

```
n <- sample(2:100, 5)
min <- NULL
max <- NULL
mapply(foo, data, n, MoreArgs=list(min, max))
```

(Also, I haven't done so here for consistency with your code, but you should almost always pass arguments to apply-type functions with names (e.g. `MoreArgs=list(min=min, max=max)`.)